# Using contact picker to get multiple data

Tags: android

I was able to successfully launch the contact picker and then set an editText in my activity to the phone number of the selected contact. What I'm trying to do now is to set two other editTexts to the first name and last name, respectively. I added the other editTexts and tried to retrieve the last and first name.

Here's what I have:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT:
            Cursor cursor = null;
            String number = "";
            String lastName = "";
            String firstName = "";
            try {
                Uri result = data.getData();
                Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "Got a contact result: "
                        + result.toString());

                // get the contact id from the Uri
                String id = result.getLastPathSegment();

                // query for phone number
                cursor = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null, Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] { id },
                        null);

                int phoneIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DATA);
                int lastNameIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds
                        .StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME);
                int firstNameIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds
                        .StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME);

                // get the phone number
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    number = cursor.getString(phoneIdx);
                    lastName = cursor.getString(lastNameIdx);
                    firstName = cursor.getString(firstNameIdx);


                    Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "Got number " + number);
                } else {
                    Log.w(DEBUG_TAG, "No results");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "Failed to get phone number data", e);
            } finally {
                if (cursor != null) {
                    cursor.close();
                }
                EditText phoneNumberEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number);
                phoneNumberEditText.setText(number);
                EditText lastNameEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.last_name);
                lastNameEditText.setText(lastName);
                EditText firstNameEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.first_name);
                firstNameEditText.setText(firstName);
                if (number.length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "No phone number found for this contact.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                if(lastName.length()==0) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "No last name found for this contact.", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                if(firstName.length()==0) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "No first name found for this contact.", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

            break;
        }

    } else {
        Log.w(DEBUG_TAG, "Warning: activity result not ok");
    }
}
```

I must be missing something basic. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String lastName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME))
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The app doesn't crash, but all I get's the phone number and not the name...

Comment: Put in a couple of Log.d() statements and watch the logCat or step through in debug mode to figure out what is being assigned to those variables.  Toasts work too.

Answer (score 0):

If you call a managedQuery it will return the contacts full name and the id but no phone number.

```
Cursor cursor =  managedQuery(intent.getData(), null, null, null, null);  
cursor.moveToNext(); String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));  
String  name=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
```